# How to find dates from a table with distinct TaskIds in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on an application in which there is a task table whose details of one year are required. The requirements are to find distinct taskIds in a given month.A taskid is repeated multiple times in a month depending on time of task processing.

Task table has columns taskId, date, workDoneinHours, status.

I have tried following code

```
declare @FROMDATE AS date = '01/01/2014'  declare @ENDDATE AS date = '12/31/2014'   

    select      distinct Task_ID

    from        Task
    WHERE       convert(date, Task.[date])>=@FROMDATE AND 
                convert(date, Task.[date])<=@ENDDATE 
    order by    Task_ID
```

The above code returns me the required distinct task Ids of whole month. The problem is that when i write date with taskid no more dublicate records are returned.

How to find distinct ids with its month?

Comment: so you have more than one task per month.

Comment: A task is processed multiple times in a  month

Comment: there are multiple tasks in a month

Comment: so out of that which one you need to select per month

Comment: all tasks done in a year with tasks in a month with same month for all that tasks showing in a column as Month

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong this is what you need.

```
SELECT Task_ID,
       [date]
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY Year([date]), Month([date]) ORDER BY [date]) AS rn,
              Task_ID,
              [Date]
       FROM   Task
       WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, Task.[date]) >= @FROMDATE
              AND CONVERT(DATE, Task.[date]) <= @ENDDATE) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**Note:** In `order by` change the order based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, it will give month-wise `task_id`s  :

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE AS DATE = '01/01/2014'
DECLARE @ENDDATE AS DATE = '12/31/2014'

SELECT Task_ID,
       Datepart(month, [date]) as [Month]
FROM   Task
WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, Task.[date]) >= @FROMDATE
       AND CONVERT(DATE, Task.[date]) <= @ENDDATE
GROUP  BY Task_ID,Datepart(month, [date])
ORDER  BY Datepart(month, [date])
```